# Laravel dispatch a Job after finishing the Job racks up memory and then fails

Tags: laravel

What I would like to do is dispatch a Job, and then continuing to dispatch the same Job after the previous one was finished so there is a continuous loop of the Job being dispatched. As indicated under option one this was previously working with the database queue driver.

I use Redis now so I can more easily monitor my jobs via Horizon.

To start the first job I use a custom artisan command, but this could as well be from within a controller, it's just the first dispatch.

My `config/horizon` (`local` config is the same as `production`):

```
'production' => [
            'supervisor-1' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue' => ['arbitrage'],
                'balance' => 'auto',
                'processes' => 2,
                'tries' => 1,
            ],
            'supervisor-2' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue' => ['trade'],
                'balance' => 'auto',
                'processes' => 4,
                'tries' => 1,
            ],
            'supervisor-3' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue' => ['balance', 'trade_meta'],
                'balance' => 'auto',
                'processes' => 5,
                'tries' => 1,
            ],
            'supervisor-4' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue' => ['notifications'],
                'balance' => 'auto',
                'processes' => 2,
                'tries' => 1,
            ],
        ],
```

**Option 1: dispatch a new job at the end of the job**

At the end of this Job's `handle()` I re-dispatch it so that it runs continuously.

This actually worked fine (the process ran for weeks on end) when using the database driver.

Job:

```
class ArbitrageJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $tries = 1;
    public $timeout = 30;

    // Process things here

    ArbitrageJob::dispatch()->onQueue('arbitrage');
}
```

**Option 2: dispatch a new job with `Queue:after`**

Job:

```
class ArbitrageJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $tries = 1;
    public $timeout = 30;
}
```

Then in AppServiceProvider:

```
Queue::after(function (JobProcessed $event) {
        ProcessArbitrage::dispatch()->onQueue('arbitrage');
});
```

What I see happening now, for both options, is that for every time it runs, it's racking up memory (I log this via `memory_get_usage(true)`).

The first run it's 28MB, the next one it's 32MB, and it keeps increasing until it's around 122MB and then I get the following error: `Illuminate\Queue\MaxAttemptsExceededException: App\Jobs\ArbitrageJob has been attempted too many times or run too long. The job may have previously timed out.`

Probably related: in `config/horizon` I've set `memory_limit` to 768MB but it looks like it fails a lot earlier than that. Or is that because it limits the memory to 128MB per worker?

Comment: that's not how jobs are supposed to be run. And if you start it with a custom command then it's not a job, it's just a command

Comment: Why are they not supposed to be run like that? After the job is finished it's re-dispatched on the queue, I'm not sure what's wrong with that? As indicated this worked perfectly with the database queue driver.
The command is just to start the process (dispatch the first job) and from there it will run continuous.

Comment: The command to start listening for jobs is `php artisan queue:work` or `php artisan queue:listen`. After that you just use `JobClass::Dispatch()` and not `dispatchNow()`.

Comment: The custom artisan command is to dispatch the first Job. The commands that you’re mentioning are irrelevant because I use Horizon that manages the queue workers.

Comment: witch method are you using for dispatching a job ?

Comment: I use dispatch();

Comment: so you have a memory leak. can you add your processing code ? if not try removing chunks of you code and see if the memory usage keeps increasing.

Comment: @N69S I've added some details and 2 options that I have tried, maybe this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved after restarting my computer. Not sure why, because I did run the commands below. I'm now using option 1 and everything works fine.

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan queue:restart
```

Answer (score 1):

You gather jobs on each other so all jobs exist behind each other so its clear that your memory should racks up.

You should use switches when use `php artisan queue:work` . I suggest that test it:

> php artisan queue:work --once
>   try other switches too that can work just last works.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow. I use horizon to run and manage my queues.